# Copy row and append it keeping the text format in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has a list of parts and serial numbers. Then I have a script that takes that list and creates a new sheet that breaks each part number/serial number into its own row if there are multiple serial numbers in the first sheet.
first sheet
item #   Desc     type    serial
231231  Baseball  sports  12322, 421321, 00000321321

second sheet
231231  Baseball  sports  12322
231231  Baseball  sports  421321
231231  Baseball  sports  321321

My problem is when I copy the last cell sometimes the numbers have leading 0's but not always some times they are text.  Everything works fine except it deletes the leading 0's

below is the code I am using.  I have tried a few things but I can't get it to copy the exact text from column d.  it always wants to delete the 0's and adding a specified set of 0's won't work because not everything has the same amount some do and some don't.

```
    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Print Avery Labels @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  function createAveryLabelsSheet() {
   Logger.clear()
  // source spreadsheets
  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('On Hands Stock'); 
 //destination spreadsheet
 var destinationSpreadSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels');
//  destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow(['Item #','Description','Type','Serial #','Print']);
  var startRow=2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 350; // Number of rows to process
  var startColumn = 1;  // A=1 B=2
  var numColumns = 9;  // Number of columns to process

//    destinationSpreadSheet.setRowHeights(2, 300, 100);


var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var column = data[i]; 
    if(column[0] != ""){
    var itemnum = column[0]; // a column
    var desc = column[1]; // b column
  var type = column[4]; // b column  
    var serial = column[3]; // b column 
    var serialnum = serial.split(", ");
var print = 'False';


      for (var j = 0; j < serialnum.length; ++j) {

        if(serial != ""){  

          var cell = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels').getRange('E'+i);
addCheckbox(cell);

  //        var setcellformat = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels').getRange('A'+i);
   //      setcellformat.setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center").setWrap(false).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize('10').setNumberFormat("@");   

          destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,serialnum[j],]);

  }else{
    var cell =  sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels').getRange('E'+i);
addCheckbox(cell);

    destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,]);
  }
}

  }
  } 
formatAverySheets();
  }

                                      function addCheckbox(cell) {  
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}


function formatAverySheets() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Avery Labels');
   var end =sheet.getLastRow();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('a2:'+end);
  //cell.sort(3);

 cell.setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center").setWrap(false).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize('10');

 var serialcell = sheet.getRange('d2:'+end);
// serialcell.setFontWeight("bold").setHorizontalAlignment("center").setWrap(false).setFontFamily('Arial').setFontSize('10').setNumberFormat('@');

 var lastcolumn =sheet.getLastColumn();
 sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, lastcolumn);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();


  AverySheeFinished();

                                      }
```

Comment: I think that in order to correctly understand your situation, providing a sample Spreadsheet will help users think of about your issue. Of course, please remove your personal information from the samples.

Comment: Attached I have included a complete copy of the Parts Order google sheet.  The part I am trying to do is take the information that is in the On Hands Sheet and import it into the Avery Label sheet.  I have the script do this already.  However when it appends the information into the Avery Labels sheet it removes any leading 0's.   The script that runs this portion is the createAveryLabelsSheet.       below is a link to the copy of my google sheet                              
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UNFsq1WTcOA9EL4PPnq7_cgJ3ZZi-mQQ

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. But it seems that the script of the shared Spreadsheet is different from that of your question. So I'm confusing about your current situation. Can you update your question using your latest information? By this, users can see about your current issue.

Comment: I updated the code to match what was above. sorry I have been trying to figure it out on my own.  The avery label sheet is how its suppose to look except where the serials are there are some that have leading 0's    For instance line 13 on the On Hands Sheet has the leading 0's but when its split and copied to the Avery Label it does not have the leading.  in the Avery Label sheet line 18-24 is line 13 split into separate rows but i need the script to keep the 0's

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the cleanest code I am sure but I found that this does work now.  I added getLastRow and then a piece of code that formats to plain text before it is entered.

```
//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Print Avery Labels @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  function createAveryLabelsSheet() {

  // source spreadsheets
  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('On Hands Stock'); 
 //destination spreadsheet
 var destinationSpreadSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels');
// destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow(['Item #','Description','Type','Serial #','Print']);
  var startRow=2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 350; // Number of rows to process
  var startColumn = 1;  // A=1 B=2
  var numColumns = 9;  // Number of columns to process

//    destinationSpreadSheet.setRowHeights(2, 300, 100);


var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var column = data[i]; 
    if(column[0] != ""){
    var itemnum = column[0]; // a column
    var desc = column[1]; // b column
    var type = column[4]; // b column  
    var serial = column[3]; // b column 
    var serialnum = serial.split(", ");
   var print = 'False';


   for (var j = 0; j < serialnum.length; ++j) {
 if(serial != ""){     
     destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type]);
   var lastrow=destinationSpreadSheet.getLastRow();
  destinationSpreadSheet.getRange('d'+lastrow).setNumberFormat('@').setValue(serialnum[+j]);         

 var cell = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels').getRange('E'+i);

   addCheckbox(cell);
      }else{

  var cell =  sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Avery Labels').getRange('E'+i);
  addCheckbox(cell);
  destinationSpreadSheet.appendRow([itemnum,desc,type,]);
   }
       }
    }
  } 
}
```